# Anyone is using swarm docker as Production?

Tags: docker, production, swarm

I'm just curious, how reliable swarm docker is ? Because I'm making decision to replace current production physical infrastructure to be a swarm docker but I'm not quite sure.

Please suggest me about swarm docker or any URL for instruction of swarm docker as a production environment.

Thanx.

Comment: hey guys, if you're downvoting a question you at least need to give your justification. This person is a newcomer. They need to know why they're being downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two versions of Swarm.

1. The original Docker Swarm introduced in late 2014. It requires external components like Consul, Etcd, Registrator, load balancer, etc. It is being used in production. It is still supported but will probably be supplanted eventually by "swarm mode" (my guess).
2. The new "Swarm Mode" introduced in June 2016. This is a much easier version as it doesn't require external services. It is however very new and still maturing. It is starting to be used in production but you need to be keenly aware of its limitations.

Overall, both Swarm versions are currently being used in production but because they are relatively new, specially Swarm Mode, they are not as mature or extensive as alternatives like Kubernetes or Mesos. But then it's really a matter of what type of production system you need. Do you need a simple 3 node High Availability system or a fully scalable hundred node system? "Production system" is become too generic a term.